# how to login to yahoo with curl php

Tags: php, curl, authentication, yahoo

hello i want login to yahoo with curl i use login jp link .  but this code dosent work how to fix this code?

i finded this code from internet

```
set_time_limit(0);

//$php_userid = 'username';
//$php_password ='password';

$php_userid = 'u';
$php_password ='p';
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt"; // Please set your Cookie File path
$fp = fopen($cookie_file_path,'w');
//$fp = fopen($cookie_file_path,'wb'); 
fclose($fp);
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.2; ja-jp; SonyEricssonSO-01C Build/3.0.D.2.79) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
$reffer = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DDD&a=11&b=4&c=2013&d=11&e=6&f=2013";

// log out.
$LOGINURL = "http://us.ard.yahoo.com/SIG=12hoqklmn/M=289534.5473431.6553392.5333790/D=mail/S=150500014:HEADR/Y=YAHOO/EXP=1135053978/A=2378664/R=4/SIG=133erplvs/*http://login.yahoo.co.jp/config/login?logout=1&.done=http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DDD&a=11&b=4&c=2013&d=11&e=6&f=2013"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);


//1. Get first login page to parse hash_u,hash_challenge

$LOGINURL = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$loginpage_html = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 

preg_match_all("/name=\".u\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $loginpage_html, $arr_hash_u);
preg_match_all("/name=\".challenge\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $loginpage_html, $arr_hash_challenge);

 $hash_u = $arr_hash_u[1][0];
 $hash_challenge = $arr_hash_challenge[1][0];



//.tries=1&.src=auc&.last=http%3A%2F%2Flogin.yahoo.co.jp%2Fconfig%2Fedit_auc&promo=&.intl=jp&.bypass=&.partner=&.u=cq4ce2ov02mdi&.v=0&.fUpdate=Y&hasMsgr=0&.chkP=Y&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fuser.auctions.yahoo.co.jp%2Fjp%2Fshow%2Fmystatus&login=********&passwd=***********
// 2- Post Login Data to Page https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?

$LOGINURL = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login";

$POSTFIELDS = '.tries=1&.src=auc&.hash=&.last=http%3A%2F%2Flogin.yahoo.co.jp%2Fconfig%2Fedit_auc&promo=&.intl=jp&.bypass=&.partner=&.u='.$hash_u.'&.v=0&.fUpdate=Y&.challenge='.$hash_challenge.'&.hasMsgr=0&.chkP=Y&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fuser.auctions.yahoo.co.jp%2Fjp%2Fshow%2Fmystatus&login='.$php_userid.'&passwd='.$php_password;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
fclose($fp);
print_r($result);


exit;
```

checked the cookie file created during yahoo login, the cookie file is complete when i try it in local (i.e logs in successfully), but the cookie file in server has totally different data, and incomplete. Like the local servers cookie file is 1 KB but on live its only 307 bytes, so cookies are not being set properly when it comes to liver

Comment: make sure error_reporting(E_ALL); , and wrap your curl_setopt in something that throws an exception when curl_setopt FAILS... you're not checking the return value of curl_setopt! function mycurl_setopt($ch,$curlopt,$val){if(false===curl_setopt($ch,$curlopt,$val){throw new Exception();}}

Comment: I don't understand "inot worked dear"

Comment: not worked you can give me one sample ?

Comment: if you can share a sample account/pass, i could make a login script for you, but i dont have a yahoo account, and i dont want to give them my phone number, which is required to make an account x.x